# How to get individual sentences matching a SOLR query in a post after finding the post

Tags: c#, regex, solr, lucene

I have indexed several documents in SOLR. Next I use a solar query e.g. `((cats dogs) AND (eat drink)) OR ("cats meow", "dogs bark")` and am able to get the documents that match the query. But along with the documents for which there was a match, I also need (for each document) the individual sentences for which the query matched. 
       The way I am doing it currently, is that once I get the matched document from SOLR I iterate through each sentence in the document and use c# regex to see which sentences actually matched for the query.
       Is there a simpler way to do this using SOLR itself ? Do I need to index every individual sentence from a post ? I am trying to explore SOLR highlighting feature but not sure if the SOLR highlight feature would return me individual sentences (I believe it returns just a group of words not a sentence - please correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: Does [HighlightingParameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters) on Solr's Wiki help you?

Comment: Does the highlighting feature work with complex Solr queries (ones with ANDs, ORs) ? I am still trying to figure out. I have been able to get it work fine for single words but I am not sure if it works for the kind of query example I have provided above.